# Tkinter Text White Shadow on Darker Screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

There is a white shadow on my text when displayed on a darker background:

```
screen = tkinter.Canvas(width=145, height=650, highlightthickness=0)
screen.master.overrideredirect(True)
screen.master.lift()
screen.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
screen.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
screen.master.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white')


text = Text(screen, width=145, height=40)  
text.tag_configure("tag_name", justify='right')
text.pack()
text.insert('1.0', 'This is a test')
Font_tuple = ("Times new roman", 13, "bold") 
text.configure(font=Font_tuple)
text.tag_add("tag_name", "1.0", "end")
```

[image]

Tried this:

```
import ctypes
```

```
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```

Comment: It is caused by the *anti-aliasing* effect when rendering the text.